# Missing '$template' parameter on emails

Tags: email, prestashop

I'm trying to send an email after our IPN sends payment status updates, and email customers as well.  I have the following code

```
$file_attachement = null; 
Mail::Send( (int)$email_order->id_lang, 
'order_conf', 
Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$email_order->id_lang), 
null, 
$email_customer->email, 
$email_customer->firstname.' '.$email_customer->lastname, 
null, 
null, 
$file_attachement, 
null, 
_PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$email_order->id_shop );
```

And I get the following error

```
Missing '$template' parameter...smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 177
```

The `order_conf` exists, and I can look at the `Advanced Parameters->Email` and see that its trying to send.

Prestashop Version is 1.7.5.1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any theme, try to copy the email templates (for every lang), to the theme mail directory.

Comment: It's a default install, no changes at all

Comment: Also the default install, use the `classic` theme. Try to copy the mail folder to themes/classic or themes/classic/templates

Answer (score 0):

Mails are templated. You have to pass the data for the template mechanism.

Your data parameter is null.

```
<?php

$file_attachement = null; 
Mail::Send(
    (int)$email_order->id_lang, 
    'order_conf', 
    Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$email_order->id_lang), 
    $YOUR_DATA_ARRAY_NOT_NULL, 
    $email_customer->email, 
    $email_customer->firstname.' '.$email_customer->lastname, 
    null, 
    null, 
    $file_attachement, 
    null, 
    _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$email_order->id_shop );

?>
```

You can get an idea of how to get these data from [the source code of Prestashop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/34816030dd86087df9cfcc0732cb928b265af5a0/classes/PaymentModule.php)